# CountVectorizer matrix varies with new test data for classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization

I have created a model for text classification using python. I have CountVectorizer and it results in a document term matrix of 2034 rows and 4063 columns ( unique words ). I saved the model I used for new test data. My new test data

```
 test_data = ['Love', 'python', 'every','time']
```

But the problem is I converted the above test data tokens into a feature vector, but it differs in shape. Because the model expect a 4063 vector. I know how to solve it by taking vocabulary of CountVectorizer and search for each token in test data and putting it in that index. But is there any easy way to handle this problem in scikit-learn itself.

Answer (score 10):

You should not fit a new CountVectorizer on the test data, you should use the one you fit on the training data and call `transfrom(test_data)` on it.

Comment: Muller - Hey I dint get exactly what you mean.                                           from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
train_data_features = count_vect.fit_transform(train_data)                 So, if a new data is coming say "I love python so much", I need to transorm into the same shape as that of the model , with number of rows as same vocabulary before. Please tell how will I do that .

Comment: count_vect.transform(["I love python so much"]).

Answer (score 5):

*You have two ways to solve this*

**1. you can use the same CountVectorizer that you used for your train features like this**

```
cv = CountVectorizer(parameters desired)

X_train = cv.fit_transform(train_data)

X_test = cv.transform(test_data)
```

**2. You can also creat another CountVectorizer, if you really want to(but not advisable since you would be wasting space and you'd still want to use the same parameters for your CV), and use the same feature.**

```
cv_train = CountVectorizer(parameters desired)

X_train = cv_train.fit_transform(train_data)

cv_test = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=cv_train.get_feature_names(),desired params)

X_test = cv_test.fit_transform(test_data)
```

Comment: in No  [1.]:
X_test = cf.transform(test_data) ??.... cf means CV right?

Comment: ahh yeah. thats prolly a typo. Will update @taufikedys

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
test_features = inverse_transform(test_data)
```

this should return you what you wish for.

Answer (score 0):

I added .toarray() to the wole command in order to see the results as a matrix.
so you should write:
X_test_analyst = Pipeline.named_steps['count_vectorizer'].transform(X_test).toarray()

Answer (score 0):

I'm mega late for this discussion, but I just want to leave something for people come from the search engine. 
Sorry for my bad English. 
;)

As mention by @Andreas Mueller, you shouldn't create a new CountVectorizer with your new data(set), u can imagine what count vectorizer do is make a 2d array(or think as a excel table), every column is a unique word, every row representing a document(or sentence), and the value (i,j) means in i^th sentence, the frequency of j^th word. 

If you make a new CountVectorizer using your new data, the unique word probably(if not must) be different. When u make model.predict using this data, it will report some sort of error telling u the dim are not correct.

What I did in my code is the following: 
If you train your model in different .py / .ipynb file, you can use `import pickle` followed by `dump` function for your fitted count vectorizer. You can follow the detail in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55066/how-to-export-pca-to-use-in-another-program). 
If you train your model in same .py/.ipynb file, you can directly follow what @Andreas Mueller said.

code:

```py
import pickle
pk.dump(vectorizer,open(r'/relative path','wb'))
pk.dump(pca,open(r'/relative path','wb'))
# ...

# When you want to use:
import pickle
vectoriser = pk.load(open(r'/relative path','rb'))
pea = pk.load(open(r'/relative path','rb'))
#...
```

Side note:
If I remember correctly, you can also export class or other things using pickle, but when you did so, make sure the class is already defined when you load the object. Not sure if this matters in this case, but I still import PCA and CountVectorizer before I did the pk.load function.
I'm just a beginner in coding so please test my code before use it in your project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).